# Get Woocommerce customer orders

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is is possible to get current and previous customer order? Namely I need Billing Address of current order and Billing Address of previous order per customer.

For example I need to get array of every Customer Order, namely I need Billing Address from every customer order.

So I have some code that print any text at "Edit Order page" in admin panel.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'edit_woocommerce_order_page', 10, 1 );

function edit_woocommerce_order_page($order){
global $post_id;
$order = new WC_Order( $post_id );
echo '<p><strong>Some text here</strong> ' . get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_shipping_field_value', true ) . '</p>'; 
}
```

As you can see it displays Some text for every user. I guess I should get some array of every customer and display Order array with order ID and Billing Address 1. Check screenshot please
[Code above adds text in Edit Order page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikfuH.png)

Is it possible?

Comment: In the order there is a link "view other orders" where will list all of the customer orders. So why not adding a column in orders showing billing address ? in order its self listing so many addresses will couse you issues in future. But its possible yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will grab all completed orders if customer is not a guest.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'edit_woocommerce_order_page', 10, 1 );

function edit_woocommerce_order_page($order){
$customer_id =  $order->get_user_id();
//Check if its guest or not
if($customer_id != 0):
    $args = array(
        'customer_id' => $customer_id,
        'status' => array('wc-completed'), //Change if needed
        'exclude' => array( $order->get_id() ), // We dont need current order
    );
    $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
    if($orders):
        foreach($orders as $k=>$order):
            echo '<p><strong>Some text here</strong>'.$order->get_billing_address_1().'</p>';
        endforeach;
    endif;
endif;
}
```

Limit to last 2 orders

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'edit_woocommerce_order_page', 10, 1 );
    
    function edit_woocommerce_order_page($order){
    $customer_id =  $order->get_user_id();
    //Check if its guest or not
    if($customer_id != 0):
        $args = array(
            'customer_id' => $customer_id,
            'status' => array('wc-completed'), //Change if needed
            'limit' => 2,
        );
        $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
        if($orders):
            foreach($orders as $k=>$order):
                echo '<p><strong>Some text here</strong>'.$order->get_billing_address_1().'</p>';
            endforeach;
        endif;
    endif;
    }
```

Getting current order and previous one only

```
function edit_woocommerce_order_page($order){
    $customer_id =  $order->get_user_id();
    //We need current order id to know where we start
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    if($customer_id != 0):
        $args = array(
            'customer_id' => $customer_id,
            'status' => array('wc-completed'), //Change if needed
            'return' => 'ids', // Grab all order ids for customer 
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
        $all_order_ids = wc_get_orders( $args );
        //Find current order key 
        $all_order_id_keys = array_flip(array_keys($all_order_ids));
        $current_order_key = array_keys($all_order_ids, $order_id);
        //Grab all values from our array
        $all_order_id_values = array_values($all_order_ids);
        //From all values we look for current order key and we increase that key with 1 to grab prev order id by key
        $previous_order_id = $all_order_id_values[$all_order_id_keys[$current_order_key[0]]+1];
        $order_args = array(
            'post__in' => array($order_id,$previous_order_id),
        );
        $orders = wc_get_orders( $order_args );
        if($orders):
            foreach($orders as $k=>$order):
                echo $order->get_id(); // For testing 
                echo '<p><strong>Some text here</strong>'.$order->get_billing_address_1().'</p>';
            endforeach;
        endif;
    endif;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'edit_woocommerce_order_page', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: You are awesome, thank you! But is it possible not exclude current order billing address? I mean for example customer order id is 307, but he has 310, 308, 307, 300, 250. Is it possible to display only current(307) and 300. So it should be displayed only current and previously order

Comment: just limit to 2 that will return last 2 and remove exclude. I have updated my answer

Comment: You are awesome:) But when I look order number 307(as example), it still shows me order 310, 308. I'd like to see current order and previous. I mean if I look at order 310(as example), I also need to see order 309(as example). It is orders by customer. So I don't need to see orders 311, 312, 312... Just current and previous one:) Thank you!

Comment: @Alina are orders 310 and 309 for same customer ? Sounds like 309 is not from the same customer. Also we are loooking for completed orders.

Comment: Yes, orders from the same order:) Thank you!*

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if thats what you wanted.